# Run Galde Gtk3+ Python under Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, gtk3, glade

i've created a student-managing-software for linux which use different packages (tkmessageboxes, glade-builder, gtk3+). Now, there are a lot of people how asked how it can be used under windows but i've no idea. So, does someone know how to use these packages under windows or is it impossible? THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would say it is up to the developer to make an actual installer for it, but you can get all of the dependencies through the [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) project.

Comment: Thx for the tipp. Yeah, i think i will need to re-create the application with windows-librarys :) but i will try this!